# Creating a Spring enum bean and passing the value of a method call

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have this Singleton:

```
   public enum Elvis {
       INSTANCE;
       private int age;

       public int getAge() {
           return age;
       }
   }
```

I know how to create the enum bean in spring:

```xml
   <bean id="elvis" class="com.xyz.Elvis" factory-method="valueOf">
           <constructor-arg>
               <value>INSTANCE</value>
           </constructor-arg>
   </bean>
```

How do I pass the int returned by INSTANCE.getAge() into another beans constructor?

Comment: Any idea how you would pass just Elvis to a field expecting an Enum? If I use #{T(Elvis)} it tells me it can't convert from java.lang.Class to java.lang.Enum.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html):

```xml
<constructor-arg value = "#{elvis.age}" />
```

or without `elvis` bean:

```xml
<constructor-arg value = "#{T(com.xyz.Elvis).INSTANCE.age}" />
```

Comment: Small correction for calling age method:

<constructor-arg value = "#{T(com.xyz.Elvis).INSTANCE.age()}" />