# Spring singleton implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I've a singleton utility helper class which has `getInstance()` method, it lazily initializes and returns the instance. I always use `getInstance()` for getting the instance. I'm only making it Spring component only because I need to access to some other spring beans inside my utility class.

In the same time, this class is spring bean scoped singleton by default.

Should I implement only [simple lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Lazy_initialization) or should I use it with  double-checked locking for multi-threaded application?

Or Spring bean singleton will guarantee this single instance during whole lifecycle of the application?

Comment: ill sugest you to use Enum as singleton, it will be both guarantee single instance and thread safe. look at this question and accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702693/creating-a-spring-enum-bean-and-passing-the-value-of-a-method-call

Comment: You should be avoiding double checked locking as it is not guaranteed to always perform as expected. http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or Spring bean singleton will guarantee this single instance during whole lifecycle of the application?

Spring loads its beans in a single thread so you do not have to worry about double-checked locking as long as your spring bean is accessed during spring wiring and not at a later time.  In other works, if your helper class is passed in as a Spring `property` to another bean then the `getInstance()` will be called then in a single threaded context.

If, however, you are injecting the *factory* into another class and there is a chance that the `getInstance()` method will be called *after* the wiring completes then you should worry about protecting it against multi-thread initialization.

Comment: Thanks Gray! This class is utility class and in the same time it is spring singleton bean. So only if I'm calling `getInstance()`, I should protect it against multi-thread initiliziation, did I get it correct?

Comment: use `factory-method` to call getInstance and it gets called at load time by spring.